# unix search/replace with wildcard

Tags: php, regex, eclipse, unix

I'm not very good at scripting, nor am I very good at regex, so I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

what I'd like to do is run a unix command that will search within current (and sub-) directories for a particular pattern match, and replace it with another string/pattern.

Lots of articles on this, but my 'twist' is that the match must have a wildcard - which will be reproduced in the replacement string.

I'm resorting to this method as I don't think I can get this specific with Eclipse (for PHP). If this CAN be done with Eclipse, please let me know.

For instance, here is the pattern I'm looking for:  `::$_<sometext>` and I wish to replace it with `::myFunction('<sometext>')`.

Here is an example:
`echo UserClass::$_thevariable;`
turns into:
`echo UserClass::getVar('thevariable');`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think this thread might be where you want to start, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files.

Comment: @chris85 - I already looked at that - and while it is a good lesson for matching /replacing fixed strings, I didn't see anything about the wildcard twist I am referring to. I need to capture the wildcard so I can place the `')` after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -exec sed -i -E -e "s/::[$]_([a-zA-Z]+)/::getVar('\1')/g" {} \;
```

But be careful with `sed -i`, it replaces files in place... Also this works for the specified search/replace strings, it might be more compicated if you need to escape things

Comment: but what if thevariable has too many options to list them all? I would like to do this without specifying 'thevariable'. this means ANY `::$_text` would be replaced with `::myfunction('text')`

Comment: clarify a bit more! What's the "end" of the replacement? Until the 1st space? First ";"? Not clear enough

Comment: Sorry - the "end" of the replacement is the first non-alpha character (A-Z or a-z). This means it terminates at `)`, `,`, `;`, or space

Comment: No. I don't have numbers in my variables, but in the interest of keeping this generic numbers should be ok (part of variable name)

Comment: Wait, what about the underscore after the dollar sign?

Comment: Sorry I missed it. Added the _